# SQL: get records based on user likes of other records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write an SQL (Windows server) query that will provide some results based on what other users like.

It is a bit like on Amazon when it says 'Users who bought this also bought...'

It is based on the vote field, where a vote of '1' means a user liked a record; or a vote of '0' means they disliked it.

So when a user is on a particular record, I want to list 3 other records that users who liked the current record also liked.

snippet of relevant table provided below:

```
            ID  UserID      Record ID   Vote   DateAdded
            16  9999        12013011290  1     2008-11-11 13:23:44.000
            17  8888        12013011290  0     2008-11-11 13:23:44.000
            18  7777        12013011290  0     2008-11-11 13:23:44.000
            20  4930        12013011290  1     2013-11-19 15:04:06.263
```

I think this requires ordering by a sub-select, but I'm not sure. Can anyone advise me on if this is possible and if so how! thanks.

p.s.
To maintain the quality of the results I think it would be extra useful to filter by DateAdded. That is, 
 - 'user x' is seeing recommended records about 'record z'
 - 'user y' is someone who has *liked* 'record z' and 'record a'
 - only count 'user y's' *like* of 'record a' IF they *liked* 'record a' an HOUR before or after they *liked* 'record z'
 - in other words, only count the 'record a's' *like* if it was during the same website-browsing session as 'record z'

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: What would be the basis for the like it near the same time?  Other items with the most likes would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
select r.description
from record r
join (
     select top 3 v.recordid from votes v
     where v.vote = 1 and recordid != 123456789
     and userid in
       (
          select userid from votes where recordid = 123456789 and vote =1
       )
     order by dateadded desc  
) as x on x.recordid = r.id
```

Comment: That is other users that liked.  Not what other users liked.

Answer (score 0):

A method I used for the basic version of this problem is indeed using multiple selects: figure out what users liked a specific item, then query further on what they tagged.

```
with Likers as
   (select user_id from likes where content_id = 10)
select count(user_id) as like_count, content_id
   from likes
   natural join likers
   where content_id <> 10
   group by content_id
   order by like_count desc;
```

(Tested using Sqlite3)

What you will receive is a list of items that were liked by everyone who liked item 10, ordered by the number of likes (within the search domain.)  I would probably want to limit this as well, since on a larger dataset its likely to result in a large amount of stray items with only one or two similar likes that are in turn buried under items with hundreds of likes.

I suspect the reason you are checking timestamps in the first place is so that if somebody likes laundry detergent, then comes back two days later to like a movie, the system would not associate "people who like Epic Shootout 17 also like Clean More."

I would not recommend using date arithmetic for this.  I might suggest creating another table to represent individual "sessions" and using the `session_id` for this task.  Since there are (hopefully!) many, many like records on your database, you want to reduce the amount of work you are making it do.  You can also use this `session_id` for logging any other actions a person did (for analytics purposes.)  It is also computationally cheaper to ask for all things that happened *within a session* with a simple index and identity comparison than to perform date computations on potentially millions of records.

For reference, [Piwik defines a new session as thirty minutes since the last action taken](http://piwik.org/faq/general/faq_36/).